# When does a pilot ask for landing clearance, and when do they recieve it?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control

Could a pilot flying directly overhead of the airport gain landing clearance, Could a pilot on the wrong end of runway heading get landing clearance, Or would they require approach instructions, or line up themselves first?

Comment: You already asked this question, and received answers here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/72154/does-a-pilot-need-clearance-to-enter-the-traffic-pattern/72334#72334

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does a pilot need clearance to enter the traffic pattern?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/72154/does-a-pilot-need-clearance-to-enter-the-traffic-pattern)

Answer (score 3):

You normally never ask for a landing clearance itself. At a VFR airport the controller is mentally sequencing aircraft as they arrive and are cleared into the zone, and gives routing instructions as necessary to make aircraft find their way onto final in the desired sequence with the necessary spacing.  Having already been cleared into the control zone the airport is in, and following routing or reporting instructions provided in your clearance to enter the zone or to start an instrument approach, it'll be provided by the tower without prompting when the tower is satisfied the runway is clear, or will be clear shortly, and you are correctly in position as #1 in the sequence.

The only time you ever ask for a clearance at a controlled airport is if it's unusually late due to controller distractions, and the controller hasn't issued a "cleared to land" by some critical point where you need to know one way or another what the plan is.  At a VFR controlled airport I might speak up while on final at maybe 300 feet or so if I haven't heard from the controller.  On an instrument approach I would speak up if I haven't received a landing clearance shortly after passing the final approach fix.

In both of these cases it's a situation where you are waiting for the clearance, none is forthcoming, and you allow for the possibility the controller is busy with other tasks and keep waiting until you reach a point where it's "ok I gotta know one way or the other; time to speak up".  Sometimes you'll just about to key the mic to ask and the controller will pipe in with "cleared to land" and you can tell from the tone they've caught themselves just in time.

Comment: Nit: ICAO rules only allow clearing one plane at a time to guarantee separation, but FAA rules allow multiple clearances under "anticipated separation".

Comment: I'm in Canada but taking it to the extreme I remember that kind of thing at Oshkosh.  3 airplanes landing on the same runway at the same time, one going short , one medium, and one long.

Comment: @StephenS Actually not 100% true. Look up "Reduced runway separation" and ICAO DOC 4444 section 7.10.2

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad, as flights can be conducted in several different ways and the events leading up to a landing clearance are different.

Generally speaking, ATC will be aware of a flight some time before a landing clearance has to be issued. The actual landing clearance is typically issued somewhere between 5 minutes to 30 seconds before touchdown.

If the flight is operated under instrument flight rules (IFR), ATC will basically handle the flight from start to finish. During the approach, the pilot will be instructed to contact the tower, who will issue a landing clearance when appropriate (the pilot never explicitally requests a landing clearance - everyone knows the flight is inbound to land).

If operating under visual flight rules (VFR) a bit more is left up to the pilot. Normally, a pilot will request to enter the controlled airspace immediately surrounding the airport. The tower will issue instructions regarding approaching the airport and joining the "landing circuit" (the standard route to fly on approach to any runway). Once in the circuit, and when appropriate, tower will issue a landing clearance. Again, the pilot does not explicitally request it, since the pilot would have informed ATC of their intentions when entering the local airspace, so ATC already knows the pilot wants to land.

Could a pilot flying directly overhead get a landing clearance? Sure, but he would be talking to ATC for some time before flying overhead, since that would be inside controlled airspace - which you can't enter without a clearance.

Could a pilot on the wrong end of the runway get a landing clearance? Sure, but, again, the pilot would be talking to ATC long before reaching the runway. The pilot is always free to request another runway for landing than the runway in use ("the wrong end"). Weather, traffic and local regulations permitting, ATC will accommodate such a request.

Comment: What if the pilot wants a touch and go or stop and go?

Comment: @JamesDavis He will tell ATC during approach, typically on downwind